# Keep Google Map <div> fixed while background <div>s scroll

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to keep a Google Map div fixed on the screen while my background, which will be composed of successive divs encapsulating content, can scroll.

I've tried wrapping the map div in another fixed div but this only makes the map div vanish.

**HTML**

```
<body>

    <div id="map" style="position: fixed;"></div>

    <div class="backdiv1">
        <div class="content">
            <h1>TITLE</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="background">
            <p>CONTENT</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="backdiv2">
        <div class="content">
            <h1>TITLE</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="background">
            <p>CONTENT</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="backdiv3"> <!--et cetera-->
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body, #map    {
    font-family: Nobel;
    font-size: small;
    background: gray;
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#map  {
    width: 100%;
    height: 65.85%;
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    z-index: 10
}

.backdiv1   {
    top:0%;
    left: 0%;
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 1;
}

.backdiv2   {
    top: 100%;
    left: 0%;
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    z-index: 1;
}

.backdiv3    { 
    top: 200%
    left: 0%
    /*et cetera*/
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you code seems to do what you want. It keeps the map fixed and the rest of the divs scroll as expected.. what is the actual problem ?

Comment: hey Gaby, the map will not stay fixed in place. I'd like my stack of background divs "backdiv (i)" to scroll but for the map to always be on top occupying ~66% of the screen. I only want the divs to be visible at the bottom 33%.
Examining the code with Chrome DT, it lists, within :

<div id="map" style="position:relative; overflow:hidden; transform: translateZ(0px); background-color: rgb (0,84,143);">

although this is not how I've defined the map div in my HTML and CSS.

I suppose that Google Maps API v3 is causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. The map API sets the `position` to `relative` on the map element.

You should wrap the map in another element (*as you tried*), but give it the properties you were trying to give to `#map` (*and apply to `#map` just the width/height properties*)

```
.map-position  {
    width: 100%;
    height: 65.85%;
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

---

You should also set the `top` of the first div (`.backdiv1`) to `65.85%` so it starts after the map (*this way you can see it in full*)

Demo at http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vOMgEV